# Google Plus Client Class for ACTION_SEND Intent

Tags: android, twitter, client, google-plus

I implemented posting on Twitter using this code

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setClassName("com.twitter.android", "com.twitter.android.PostActivity");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);
        startActivity(sharingIntent);
```

Now I'm thinking of doing the same thing for Google+ but I can't find the class/package for it. Does anyone know which one is it or a way to find it out? Thank you! :)

Comment: Hi There. Do you know the class to only open Twitter Home Page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(ShareActivity.this)
   .setText("This site has lots of great information about Android!
      http://www.android.com")
   .setType("text/plain")
   .getIntent()
   .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");

startActivity(shareIntent);
```

[Check here](http://googleplusplatform.blogspot.in/2012/05/sharing-rich-content-from-your-android.html) for more details.